# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) in OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

This works when I use webcam, but when I use ImageGrab I get an error

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
while 1:
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, 1919, 1075))
    img_np = np.array(img)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    ret, frame1 = frame #error here
```

Comment: why do you write `ret, frame1 = frame`? what values do your variables hold?

Comment: after trying for a while ret, frame1 = frame  was the only thing that worked to compare 2 frames. the full script detects motion which initially used webcam but when I switched to screen capture it stopped working

Answer (score -1):

You are probably getting this error because frame is a single unpackable array hence you are trying to assign a single value into two variables ret and frame1 hence you are getting the error. If you intend to assign the same value to both ret and frame1 you can do as:-

```
ret,frame1=frame,frame
```

If you want to split the array you can use numpy split function.

Comment: that answer makes no sense, especially your line of code. please explain.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz In python when you perform assignment to variables in this fashion i.e. x,y=value then,the python expect value to be a tuple like (a,b) so it assigns the first value i.e a to x and b to y. In the above case the value which is being tried to assigned is not of that type and hence it can't be unpacked in similar fashion which is resulting in error. Talking about the code part ret,frame1=frame,frame means we assign same value i.e the value of frame to both ret and frame.